# Finding a singular point for the given differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to show that $x = 0$ is a regular point for this ODE:

$xy'' + (1-x)y' + \lambda y = 0$

What I have tried:

writing the equation above in these two general forms:

1. $y'' = p(x)y' + q(x)y = 0$
2. $x^2y'' xP(x)y' + Q(x)y = 0$

we then get:

$p(x) = 1-\frac{1}{x}$ **or** $\frac{(1-x)}{x}$
$q(x) = \frac{\lambda}{x} $

Then

$P(x)= x(1-\frac{1}{x})=x-1$
$Q(x) = \frac{\lambda}{x}\cdot x^2 = \lambda x $

How should I understand the process of a regular singular point? do I replace every $x$ value as $0$ and see if the equation is equal to $0~$? or assume as $x \to 0$ they remain finite hence $x = 0$ is there an inductive process behind understanding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Definition:** Consider the general homogeneous second order linear differential equation $$u''+P(x)u'+Q(x)u=0\tag1$$
> where $x \in D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.
>
> - The point $x_0 \in D$ is said to be an **ordinary point** of the above given differential equation if $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are analytic at $x_0$.
> - If either $P(x)$ or $Q(x)$ fails to be analytic at $x_0$, the point $x_0$ is called a **singular point** of the given differential equation.
> - A singular point $x_0$ of the given differential equation is said to be **regular singular point** if the function $(x-x_0)P(x)$ and $(x-x_0)^2 Q(x)$ are analytic at $x_0$ and **irregular** otherwise.

${}$

The given differential equation $~xy'' + (1-x)y' + \lambda y = 0~$ can be written as $$y'' + \left(\dfrac 1x-1\right)y' + \lambda \dfrac yx = 0$$which is of the form equation $(1)$ where $~P(x)=1/x-1~$ and $~Q(x)=\lambda/x~.$

Clearly both the $~P(x)~$ and $~Q(x)~$ are not analytic at $~x_0=0~.$ Therefore $~x_0=0~$ is the singular point of the given differential equation.

Now since $$(x-x_0)P(x)=x \left(\dfrac 1x-1\right)=1-x$$ and

$$(x-x_0)^2 Q(x)=x^2 \frac{\lambda}{x}=\lambda x$$

so both are analytic at $x_0=0$, and hence $x_0=0$ is regular singular point.